# Does the GA event first_open even trigger without tracking consent?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

As the title suggests, I am wondering whether consent is required for the standard even, First_open in GA4 app analytics can be triggered even though consent has not been accepted (yet). I am asking because the first_open event is significantly lower than the amount of downloads. Does this mean that the app is never opened or that users simply deny tracking consent?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will split your question to two areas.

**1. Difference between downloads and first_open.**

This could be normal state. I mean that it depends on your industry. Another ratio between downloads and first opens would be for banking or gaming sector.

**2. Measure user activities without consent**

Google Analytics 4 offers "Google Consent Mode", which allow you collect anonymised data from users. If you implement Google Consent Mode, first_open will be collected even though user didn't give you a consent.

Also you should investigate, what happens if user doesn't give you consent what you are doing with Firebase SDK. Is it being turned on or off?

And one more thing. What kind of consent you are talking about? Basically there are two types of consent:

1. "Cookie" Consent which aims to 3rd party identifiters (Google Consent Mode would help here). Cookies are not present in mobile apps, but this is the best naming for such consent.
2. IDFA Consent, for [iOS - Apple Tracking Transparency](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/) and for [Android - Google Privacy Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox). This consent is different to "Cookie" consent and asking for another identifier.

Answer (score -1):

It can be both. Per [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en) on `first_open`, a iOS user must opt-in to tracking in order for the event to fire properly. I am not sure iOS users can opt-in to tracking for specific apps. My understanding it was an all or nothing type of decision based on the device.

That being said, you are correct that there is a possibility that people are just downloading and not opening but I suspect this is less likely if your download numbers are significantly higher than your `first_open`.

Comment: Thank you - I'll assume that the discrepency between download numbers and first opens is thanks to a lack of tracking consent from users.  Only around 30% of iOS users has accepted tracking from my app specifically, and that number (very) roughly makes up for the difference between the numbers.